# Trying to get forest trust info but don't know how to handle empty element. C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm new to c# so I'm hoping this is an easy question.  I'm trying to query the domain for trust info which works unless an element is null.  I get "Unhandled Exception: System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryOperationException: Element not found."

If I comment out the Forest info e.g. toplevelnames, trusteddomaininfo, and excludedtoplevelnames it works.

```
class Format
{
    public static string TrustInfo(TrustRelationshipInformationCollection forestTrustCollection)
    {
        string result = "\n";
        foreach (ForestTrustRelationshipInformation trust in forestTrustCollection)
        {

            result += $"ForestName             : {Commands.GetNetForest()} \n";
            result += $"TopLevelNames           : {trust.TopLevelNames.ToString() ?? string.Empty} \n";
            result += $"ExcludedTopLevelNames   : {trust.ExcludedTopLevelNames.ToString() ?? string.Empty} \n";
            result += $"TrustedDomainInformation: {trust.TrustedDomainInformation.ToString() ?? string.Empty} \n";
            result += $"SourceName             : {trust.SourceName} \n";
            result += $"TargetName             : {trust.TargetName} \n";
            result += $"Direction               : {trust.TrustDirection} \n";
            result += $"Type                    : {trust.TrustDirection} \n";
        }

        return result;

    }


}
```

Comment: the Element probably isn't in my collection :|

Answer (score 0):

Just check if they're null before adding each result:

```
class Format
{
    public static string TrustInfo(TrustRelationshipInformationCollection forestTrustCollection)
    {
        string result = "\n";
        foreach (ForestTrustRelationshipInformation trust in forestTrustCollection)
        {

            result += $"ForestName             : {Commands.GetNetForest()} \n";
            if(trust.TopLevelNames != null)
                result += $"TopLevelNames           : {trust.TopLevelNames.ToString()} \n";
            if(trust.ExcludedTopLevelNames != null)      
                result += $"ExcludedTopLevelNames   : {trust.ExcludedTopLevelNames.ToString()} \n";
            //etc.

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what the ?? is doing in my code above?  What am I missing?  Tried the if statements and get the same result.

Comment: The ?? Wouldn't remove the whole line. They would just  instead leave $"TopLevelNames           :"

Comment: I don't know the specific domain, so if this doesn't work I can't help

Comment: Also if topLevelName were null, calling tostring on it would cause a null reference exception, so ?? Wouldn't help